# How can I control or explore a remote computer?

Tags: batch-file

How can I control or explore a remote computer? This isn't being used for anything illegal, it's to monitor my children's computers.

I already tried putting in the \ipaddress\c$ to use, but that only works for the computers on your network. They are on their own network, that must be a stronger signal than the one we have.

Example:

> main-computer - succesfully pinged 127.0.0.1
>   main-computer - connected to 127.0.0.1
>   main-computer - opening web-history.txt
>   main-computer - copying to folder "c:/monitoring"
>   main-computer - disconnecting from 127.0.0.1
>   main-computer - succesfully disconnected from 127.0.0.1

I'm trying not to use any kind of downloads or background clients.
Honestly I don't have much 'hacking' skill. And I'm trying to do this from a .bat file.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, children monitor you.

Answer (score 3):

You might look at [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553) from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021).

I feel compelled to also say that I think remotely monitoring even childrens computers is a bit unethical, and I have heard (but not tested) that a better method to observe behaviour is just to have the computer in the family loungeroom.

Comment: I fully agree. Think back, can you remember when you were young? How would you have liked your parents to be privy to all your personal concerns and thoughts?

Comment: +1: I agree with Noon as well. If you're going to be a smart parent, don't break the trust you have with your children. If you are going to monitor them, just tell them they will be monitored and do your thing. If anything, they will learn to keep you from seeing what they are doing, then maybe you can kick them out when they turn 18 because they'll have computer security jobs =P