# Bit shifting number gives wrong output `std::cout`

Tags: c++, bit-shift

```
unsigned int command = 4;
cout << command;

command = (command << 1);
cout << command;

command = (command << 1);
cout << command;
```

Output:

```
4
8
10
```

Why is is the output of the last line `10`, and not `16`?

Comment: "This is driving me nuts?" I dunno. You tell me.

Comment: Why are you using \\ instead of //?

Comment: Did you put cout in hex mode previously?

Comment: @Kerrek Yeah, and english learns you. Or was this meant serious?

Comment: @Kerrek SB So `22` is `16`? :)

Comment: And try to lower the usage of acronyms that "stand for profanity". (As this regex demonstrates: `WT[FH]`) Especially in titles. ;)

Comment: @muntoo: da, da. One guy once asked (tagged "C++", naturally) how to write software to "monitor my children". That time my comment was more apropos, "in Soviet Russia, children monitor *you*."

Comment: (Ah, I [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302886/how-can-i-control-or-explore-a-remote-computer).)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's probably a `cout << hex` somewhere before this code runs. Either that or you accidentally set `cout` to format numbers in hexadecimal. If you add:

```
command = (command<<1);
cout << command;
```

It should print out `20` in hex mode.

Comment: Yep that's it - damn obvious. Should never work after 5 on a Friday

Answer (score 0):

`10` is hexadecimal for `16`.

```
0x10 == 16
```

Sorry if I am stating the obvious.

Comment: Probably he already knew that. His question was "why is 10 coming out if I've ever seen base-10 output?"